# iOS Today Widget Dropping BT Connection

Tags: ios, bluetooth, widget, ios8-today-widget

I'm trying to use my widget to perform some bluetooth actions as a Central Manager but when I write a value to a characteristic, the connection drops after some seconds.

If I never write it the connection stays up.

Another odd thing is that the didDisconnectFromPeripheral callback is never triggered.

Ay suggestions on how to use BT with iOS widget?